# Duplicating a D3.js gauge widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, widget

I'm having some troubles when trying to implement [this widget found in Codepen](http://codepen.io/mattkeener/pen/pjGEOR) that loads in the following div:

```
<div id="action"></div>
```

The thing is I wanna use more than two of them at the same page, but when I duplicate the code, it happens [what you can see in this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/w2dz6e8t/1/) implemented into two different divs:

```
<div id="action"></div>
<div id="action2"></div>
```

As you can see, the second widget won't work, and as I did you might probably think that is related to variables that are overlapping each other, **but** if you switch the order of the divs it works! Then it doesn't make sense, if variables are overlapping then it will do it always, no matter which widget goes first.

So, maybe you are thinking: then what's the problem if you already found a solution? Well, I need to know where the problem is, cause each of them will represent some data taken from a database and they can be modified and updated individually to save the new configured data back to the DB, so when I refresh one of them in the wrong order, one of the widgets will never work, so for now I have to refresh both of them in the right order until I find what's happening, and in fact they're gonna be more than two at the same page, so it'll be inefficient refreshing all of them to avoid crashing.

Trying to deal with the problem, I think that it's not about the internal d3.js variables defined into the function ( var t,e,n,r,a,l,s,i,u,o,c,d,g ... ), cause it wouldn't make sense since they're locally scoped.

The code is hard to read cause it's minified, I used an unminifier to read it clearer, but anyway I have not much idea about D3.js...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the gauge code does such a good job following this [pattern](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) in the `render` function but loses it in the `update` function.  It starts doing global `d3.select` which only updates the *first* instance of those elements it's selecting for.  So the fix is in the update function itself, keep a reference to the `svg` element you are acting on and do further selections on that.

Further, you only need to define the `guage` function once and you should be using different variables for each instance of the gauge.

See comments below for how I changed the `guage` function:

```js
var gauge = function() {
    // added "svg"
    var svg, t, e, n, r, a, l, s, i, u, o, c, d, g, p, f, h, m, v, y, x, A, M, _, R, b, I, P, w, T = {},
        C = 120,
        k = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, C]).range([Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI]),
        z = ["rgb(235,7,27)", "rgb(242,166,0)", "rgb(139,224,91)"],
        W = 0,
        B = 50,
        E = !0,
        G = 100,
        H = 1.57,
        L = 10,
        j = !0,
        q = !0,
        D = 0,
        F = "elastic",
        J = 1e3,
        K = function(t, e) {
            var n = e ? e : 0;
            return g = 0 + (R - n) * Math.cos(t)
        },
        N = function(t, e) {
            var n = e ? e : 0;
            return p = 0 + (R - n) * Math.sin(t)
        },
        O = function() {
            return f = 0 + ((A - x) / 2 + x) * Math.cos(k(B))
        },
        Q = function() {
            return h = 0 + ((A - x) / 2 + x) * Math.sin(k(B))
        },
        S = function(t, e) {
            e.attr("points", "" + K(P(t), 2 * L) + "," + N(P(t), 2 * L) + " " + K(I(t)) + "," + N(I(t)) + " " + K(w(t), 2 * L) + "," + N(w(t), 2 * L) + " ")
        };
    return T.render = function(n) {
        var i = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, C]).range([-H, H]);
        r = k(D), a = k(D - L / 2), l = k(D + L / 2), s = d3.select("#" + _target.id).append("svg").attr("class", "pie").attr("height", e).attr("width", t), m = d3.select("#" + _target.id).append("div").attr("transform", "translate(" + M + "," + _ + ")").attr("class", "gaugeTT"), v = m.append("div").attr("class", "col1"), y = m.append("div").attr("class", "col2");
        var u = [{
                startAngle: -H,
                endAngle: H
            }],
            f = [{
                startAngle: -H,
                endAngle: 0
            }],
            h = [{
                startAngle: -H,
                endAngle: i(B)
            }];
        [{
            startAngle: i(G) - .03,
            endAngle: i(G)
        }];
        d = A - x;
        var I = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(A).innerRadius(x);
        d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(A - 1).innerRadius(x + 1);
        o = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(x + .3 * d).innerRadius(x), c = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(A).innerRadius(A - .7 * d);
        var P = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(A + 5).innerRadius(A - .7 * d),
            w = s.append("g");
            svg = w;
        w.attr("transform", "translate(" + M + "," + _ + ")").selectAll("path.bg").data(u).enter().append("path").attr("class", "bg").attr("fill", "rgb(236,229,240)").attr("d", function(t, e) {
            return I(t, e)
        }), w.attr("transform", "translate(" + M + "," + _ + ")").selectAll("path.average").data(h).enter().append("path").attr("class", "average").attr("fill", "rgb(74,0,98)").attr("d", function(t, e) {
            return o(t, e)
        }), w.attr("transform", "translate(" + M + "," + _ + ")").selectAll("path.actual").data(f).enter().append("path").attr("class", "actual").attr("d", function(t, e) {
            return c(t, e)
        }), w.append("line").attr("class", "needle-line").attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", 0).attr("x2", function() {
            return g = 0 + R * Math.cos(r)
        }).attr("y2", function() {
            return p = 0 + R * Math.sin(r)
        }), q === !0 && w.append("polygon").attr("class", "needleTip").attr("fill", b), j === !0 && (w.append("circle").attr("cx", 0).attr("cy", 0).attr("r", 45), w.select(".needle-line").style("stroke", b).style("stroke-width", 1), w.select("circle").style("fill", b)), w.append("line").attr("class", "goal-post").attr("x1", function() {
            var t = 0 + x * Math.cos(k(G));
            return t
        }).attr("y1", function() {
            var t = 0 + x * Math.sin(k(G));
            return t
        }).attr("x2", function() {
            var t = 0 + (A + 10) * Math.cos(k(G));
            return t
        }).attr("y2", function() {
            var t = 0 + (A + 10) * Math.sin(k(G));
            return t
        }).style("stroke", "rgb(82,174,201)").style("stroke-width", 5), E === !1 && w.append("circle").attr("class", "average").attr("cx", function() {
            return O(B)
        }).attr("cy", function() {
            return Q(B)
        }).attr("r", 8).style("opacity", .75).style("fill", "rgb(250,250,250)"), w.append("text").attr("class", "centerPercentage").style("fill", "#555").style("font-size", "26").attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0).attr("dy", ".35em").text("0%"), w.append("text").attr("class", "min-range").style("fill", "#555").style("font-size", "18").attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("x", -65).attr("y", 75).attr("dy", ".35em").text("0"), w.append("text").attr("class", "max-range").style("fill", "#555").style("font-size", "18").attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("x", 65).attr("y", 75).attr("dy", ".35em").text(C), w.select(".actual").on("mouseover", function() {
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(400).ease(F).attr("d", function(t) {
                return P(t)
            }), m.transition().style("opacity", "1"), w.on("mousemove", function(t) {
                var e = d3.mouse(this),
                    n = e[0] + 200 + "px",
                    r = e[1] + 200 + "px";
                console.log(e), m.style("top", r), m.style("left", n)
            })
        }), w.select(".actual").on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(400).ease(F).attr("d", function(t) {
                return c(t)
            }), m.transition().style("opacity", "0"), w.on("mousemove", null)
        })
    }, T.update = function(t) {
        u = W, W = t, v.html("<p>Acutal   " + W + "</p><p>Goal  " + G + "</p><p>Average  " + B + "</p>");
        var e = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]).range([u, t]),
            n = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 60, 120]).range(z),
            s = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, C]).range([-H, H]),
            i = [{
                startAngle: -H,
                endAngle: s(t)
            }];
        d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(A).innerRadius(x);
        // selection on svg
        svg.selectAll("path.actual").data(i).transition().ease(F).duration(J).attrTween("d", function(t) {
            var r = this.__current__;
            r || (r = {
                startAngle: -H,
                endAngle: -H
            });
            var a = d3.interpolate(r, t);
            return this.__current__ = a(1),
                function(t) {
                    return svg.attr("fill", function(r) {
                        return n(e(t))
                    }), c(a(t))
                }
        });
        var o = r,
            d = a,
            g = l;
        r = k(t), _angleC = k(B), a = k(t - L / 2), l = k(t + L / 2), I = d3.interpolate(o, r), _interpolateC = d3.interpolate(o, _angleC), P = d3.interpolate(d, a), w = d3.interpolate(g, l);
        // selections based on svg
        var p = svg.select(".centerPercentage"),
            f = svg.select("polygon");
        svg.select(".needle-line").transition().ease(F).duration(J).attrTween("x2", function() {
            return function(t) {
                return q === !0 && (S(t, f), p.text(parseInt(e(t)) + "%")), K(I(t))
            }
        }).attrTween("y2", function() {
            return function(t) {
                return N(I(t))
            }
        })
    }, T.width = function(e) {
        return arguments.length ? (t = e, T) : t
    }, T.height = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (e = t, T) : e
    }, T.needleWidth = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (L = t / 2, T) : L
    }, T.spread = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (t < Math.PI / 2 && (t = Math.PI / 2), n = t - Math.PI / 2, H = t, k = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, C]).range([Math.PI - n, 2 * Math.PI + n]), T) : H
    }, T.colors = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (i = t, T) : i
    }, T.needleColor = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (b = t, T) : b
    }, T.needleTip = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (q = t, T) : q
    }, T.target = function(n) {
        return arguments.length ? (_target = document.getElementById(n), t = _target.offsetWidth, e = _target.offsetHeight, M = t / 2, _ = e / 1.5, T) : _target
    }, T.innerRadius = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (x = t, T) : x
    }, T.outerRadius = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (A = t, R = t, T) : A
    }, T.radius = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (R = t, T) : R
    }, T.renderLine = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (j = t, T) : j
    }, T.easing = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (F = t, T) : F
    }, T.goal = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (G = t, T) : G
    }, T.average = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (B = t, T) : B
    }, T.duration = function(t) {
        return arguments.length ? (J = t, T) : J
    }, T
};

custom=gauge().target("action").outerRadius(120).innerRadius(78).radius(65).spread(2.2).goal(80).average(75).easing("linear").duration(2e3).needleWidth(23).needleColor("rgb(230,222,236)");

custom.render();
custom.update(110);

window.setTimeout(function() {
  custom.update(120);
}, 4000);

custom2=gauge().target("action2").outerRadius(120).innerRadius(78).radius(65).spread(2.2).goal(80).average(75).easing("linear").duration(2e3).needleWidth(23).needleColor("rgb(230,222,236)");

custom2.render();
custom2.update(70);

window.setTimeout(function() {
  custom2.update(68);
}, 4000);
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#action{
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  position: absolute;
}

#action2{
  top: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  position: absolute;
}

.gaugeTT{
  width: 125px;
  background-color: rgb(253,253,253);
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #777;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
.gaugeTT p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
.gaugeTT .col1{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="action"></div>
<div id="action2"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that solved it definitely! Thank you so much